# Ordering decimal numbers with ls

Tags: bash, ls

Using bash I want to list all the files contained in a directory using ls, file names are of the type "sinusoidal,V0=0.1,omega=0.5" and omega is in general a decimal number. I want to show the names in ascending order. using

```
ls -1v
```

I get for example this order

```
0.5
0.51
0.5012
0.6
```

How can I get the correct order?

```
0.5
0.5012
0.51
0.6
```

Comment: 0.5, 0.51, etc. are the name of the files?

Comment: 0.5,0.51 it's a part of the name, the complete name is sinusoidal,V0=0.1,omega=x  where x could be 0.5, 0.51 etc

Comment: What is "crescent order"?

Comment: Is this for human or programmatic use? If the output of `ls` is being read by a script, you should do this a different way; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a full explanation of why programmatic use of `ls` is inherently unsafe.

Comment: ...re: "different way", my personal preference is to generate a stream of the form `<key> <filename>\0` (where the `\0` is a literal `NUL` character), sort that stream, and then strip the keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
ls | sort
```

in bash to get the desired output.
(Given that only omega in general is a real* number. This might not work or give incorrect output if V0=0.1 can also have general values")

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1
```

In my system it giving the exact result you need.

Answer (score 0):

when I list your files with "ls -1" i will get the following,since list -1v doesn't make a difference in terms of sorting numerically these files.

```
a=0.6
omega=0.5
sinusoidal,V0=0.5102
sinusoidal,V0=0.6
```

I can put them in a column format and sort them according to number patterns

Command

```
ls -1|column -s '=' -t|sort -k2
```

Output

```
omega          0.5
sinusoidal,V0  0.5102
a              0.6
sinusoidal,V0  0.6
```

sorted by numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | sort -n
```

When I run `man sort`, I see under "Description":

> **-n**, **--numeric-sort**, **--sort=numeric**
> Sort fields numerically by arithmetic value.  Fields are supposed to have optional blanks in the beginning, an optional minus sign, zero or more digits (including decimal point and possible thousand separators).